# How Can I Replace Our Leaking Outdoor Faucet?

Tags: faucet, outdoor, leaking, outdoorfaucet

Our outdoor faucet is leaking. Here's a picture:

[image: leaky outdoor faucet, seen at an angle]

Here's another picture that more clearly shows from where I think it's leaking:

[image: leaky outdoor faucet, seen dead on, zoomed in, with arrow indicating presumed leak]

I think I need to replace the faucet. The online resources I've found warn that the pipe must be held fast when unscrewing the faucet to avoid damage. However, the pipe isn't exposed outside the wall. Unfortunately, I can't get to the pipe from the other side, either. What is the best strategy to replace the leaky faucet? Will I need to remove a section of stucco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Ecnerwal, the washer needs replacing that is around the stem. you can remove it with a wrench turning counter clockwise (CC)[image]

Once it's free turn the handle CC to remove the washer assembly. You can also wrap Graphite string (or teflon tape) around the stem and under the nut.

[image]

Comment: Teflon packing and teflon tape are *not really interchangeable* (the teflon packing is similar to the graphite string you show, but usually whiter since there's no graphite in it.) Not to say there haven't been a few at least temporarily successful kludges in the world using tape as substitute packing, but it's not the thing to buy for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Your indication of where it leaks from suggests that simply **repacking the valve stem** might fix your leak, without having to change the faucet.

If you do change the faucet, if the pipe in the basement is threaded, just unscrew it - either the pipe in the wall will unscrew, or the faucet will, and if the pipe in the wall is what unscrews, you can remove it from the faucet after it's out of the wall, attach it to the new faucet, and thread it back into the wall.

If your pipes in the basement, including this one, are soldered, you may need to unsolder it inside and pull the valve & pipe out to change the valve. One way or another that would require gaining access to the pipe.